# Connection between Operator Theory and Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras, hecke-algebras

I was wondering if there is any connection between number theory and operator theory. Especially the applications of Hardy spaces, de branges-Rovnyak spaces, Dirichlet spaces in number theory. For example to study modular forms, and etc.Something except Riemann Hypothesis.

Does anyone know any books or papers about that?

Comment: Cross posted https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459082/connection-between-number-theory-and-operator-theory